# How to run a method every time an object is accessed (or copied from/to) in a list?

Tags: python, object, methods, stack

I am try to learn about stacks while using the turtle class in Python. Basically, I write a script to draw a triangle using turtle. To do this, I made a Shape class with size and turtle as the parameters. Then, when the Shape object is initialized, it draws a triangle of given size on the screen (using the turtle).

I am pushing this Shape object onto a stack. Actually, using a for loop, I am pushing 10 triangles onto a stack! (Ten Shape objects, that is.) Then, once all 10 are in the stack, I am to pop them off the stack onto another stack. This should redraw the triangles (albeit in the opposite order).

I can't figure out how to get the turtle to redraw the triangles when they are popped and copied over and pushed into the second stack! I have also tried making the "drawing of the triangle" a method in the Shape class. This also didn't work. I also tried having the triangle drawn from a function (instead of an object), but the stack only contained None (because the function would draw the first triangle and then return None).

How can I get it to draw the triangle very time it is "moved over" to another stack (popped or pushed)?

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
from stack import *

class Shape():
    def __init__(self, size, turtle):
        self.size = size
        self.half_size = int(self.size / 2)
        self.height = int((self.size**2 + self.half_size**2)**0.5)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(self.half_size, -self.half_size)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.setposition(-self.half_size, -self.half_size)
        turtle.setposition(0, self.height - self.half_size)
        turtle.setposition(self.half_size, -self.half_size)
        turtle.penup()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 400

# initialize screen
turtle.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        
# create turtle window
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('HW Set #3 - Problem #3: Turtle Shapes')

# get the turtle and hide it
t = turtle.getturtle()
t.hideturtle()

# initialize the two stacks (these are just lists)
s1 = getStack()
s2 = getStack()

for i in range(0 , 100, 10):
    push(s1, Shape(200 - i, t))

t.showturtle()

while not isEmpty(s1) == True:
    push(s2, pop(s1))
    print(s2)
```

Comment: so, the objects aren't being copied when you pop and push. The have no knowledge of what is going on with regards to the stacks (i.e. the *lists*). You must write code that does this. The code for drawing seems to be in the `__init__` of your `Shape` class, so generally, that is code that will only get run when you instantiate an object of that class. But that only happens here: `push(s1, Shape(200 - i, t))`

Comment: That makes sense. If I move the "drawing" code to a method, I would need to call the method, which would not happen automatically when the object gets popped and pushed onto another list. The only reason I had the "drawing" code in the __init__ was because I hoped it would run again when copied. Does this make sense?

Comment: The thing that is  crucial to understand is that *nowhere do you create a copy of those objects*

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend the stack class and reimplement push and pop...inside push (or pop), draw the triangle and then call the original stack's push (or pop)

Comment: there is no stack class, and in any case, that doesn't sound like it should be the responsibility of a stack class.